# Pattern matches in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have two strings (varchar2) and I want to compare them, same like the match method from JAVA. I have two possible examples: 'GC' will match 'GC' and 'GC_DE' will match 'GC*'. I've already used `REGEXP_LIKE` but this method caused a problem because the next condition is true - `REGEXP_LIKE ('ABVCDRC-OM', 'CB*')`,  even if the `'ABVCDRC-OM'` does not starts with `CB`. Is there any way to do this?

details: `T_COUNTRY` contains entries like `'GC_DE', 'GC_GB', 'GC_GE', 'GC_RO'`. I want to show all the records but filtered by entries from `T_FILTER ('GC_R*')`. The entries are not always like GC. I could have also OC_ or GV etc, depending on user input..So I need to compare to db fields with no fixed values. Using select *...where `REGEXP_LIKE (entity_id, filter_id)` will not solved my problem.

Comment: Isn't this a simple `WHERE T_COUNTRY LIKE 'GC_R%'`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use like '%GC_DE%'

Comment: if you want to search strings that start with CB, have you tried REGEXP_LIKE ('ABVCDRC-OM', '^CB')

Answer (score 0):

I would use e.g. `REGEXP_LIKE` but I would define a regular expression more precisely as `'^GC_[A-Z]{2}$'`. This will ensure that only `GC_xx` strings are matched.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the entries are not always like GC and something. I could have also OC_ or GV etc..So I need to compare to db fields with no fixed values.

Comment: So just try use better regular expression '^(GC|OC)_[A-Z]{2}$' or more generally '^[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}$'.

Answer (score 0):

The Like (%GC%) should work the way you need it to.

`when T_FILTER like (%GC%)` would give you everything with GC in it.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the entries are not always like GC and something. I could have also OC_ or GV etc..So I need to compare to db fields with no fixed values.